# XSD: Content of an element does not matter

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having some issues on achieving the following in my XSD Schema.
I have an XML in which a data element is found. The content of this data element can vary
depending on different transformations that take place. So I can't really put one schema on it.

I just want to ignore everything inside the data element, and let it just pass the schema without errors.

My XML:

```
<root>
    <element1>12345</element1>
    <element2>abcde</element2>
    <data>
        <lots></lots>
        <of></of>
        <content></content>
    </data>
</root>
```

In my XSD I do the following:

```
<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" />
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I thought of using processContents skip for this problem, but somehow, that doesn't work.
Does anybody know why it doesn't work, or have a better solution at hand?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. The problem in your example is that only *one* element is allowed inside `<data>`, since you didn't declare `maxOccurs` and the default is *one*. If you change it to

```
<xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

it should validate.

See **[fiddle](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=e3f8dc6e-b070-421e-89ad-9611a957101c-xsdvalidation#.U43X0pRdWcw)**.